# RHEL 6.10 updated to 7.9, install grub2 issue

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, grub2

After upgrading RHEL 6.10 to 7.9
I'm having issues installing grub2:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /boot/efi/EFI/redhat from install of grub2-common-1:2.02-0.87.e17_9.9.noarch conflicts with file from package grub-1:0.97-99.e16.x86_64
```

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a remnant of RHEL6's GRUB still in place. Remove it with e.g. `rpm -e grub`, then retry your installation of GRUB2.